# Definition and Purpose of visual SALIENCY

Tags: image, image-processing

Salient object in an image is that part of the image where all the human attention goes and rest part is mostly ignored by the vision of humans.
i wonder why many people researching about saliency. i can't get enough illustration how saliency would be any of use to human in the world. could u give me any example that describe usefullness of saliency?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the place where you should ask this kind of questions, because here we can help you with problems in your code...

But anyway, I will try to explain it. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salience_%28neuroscience%29):

> Saliency detection is considered to be a key attentional mechanism
>   that facilitates learning and survival by enabling organisms to focus
>   their limited perceptual and cognitive resources on the most pertinent
>   subset of the available sensory data.

So in order to survive you use the visual saliency. In an primitive world, suppose you were hunting. If anything moved in the forest the saliency generated by the movement would made you react immediatelly.

Examples:

- Suppose you are driving and suddenly a truck appears.
  You react immediatelly because of the saliency generated by the
  moving truck.
- Suppose you are driving and suddenly a cyclist appears
  (wearing yellow clothes). The saliency focus your attention in the cyclist and you slow down your car.

You can learn a little bit more [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Visual_salience).

Comment: ups, sorry, ok, i got it.  
and thanks, for examples